# How do optimise sql query using join between multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

i have two tables having following structure 
**Table A**

```
itemId    categoryId     orderDate
==========================================
   1          23            2016-11-08
   1          23            2016-11-12
   1          23            2016-11-16
```

**Table B**    have the structure

```
 categoryId  stock     price 
 ==========================================

  23          500       600
```

However mine desired output should be as like
  **Result C**

```
 price         stock               orderdate                               qty
  600           500               2016-11-08 (first order date)            3 (3 time appearance in first table)
```

Here is what i have tried so far

```
select b.price,b.stock from B b, A a
where b.categoryId = (
    select a.categoryId
    from A
    GROUP BY categoryId
    HAVING COUNT(categoryId)>1
    )
and (a.orderdate = (
  select MIN(orderdate)
  from A
  where categoryId = b.categoryId)
  )
```

i have following result

```
price         stock             orderdate                              
600           500               2016-11-08
```

i have no idea how do find `qty` as it is appeared 3 times in first table.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the records in table a grouped by item id and category id, so include these two in your group by statement. Then the other columns you have to aggregate using MIN, MAX, AVG, SUM, etc. I use MIN which will give you the smallest number in the group for that particular column, although it shouldn't matter in this case whether you use MIN or MAX or AVG - it's all the same. Then COUNT(*) will just count the number of recrods in the group.

Also, joins are generally preferred over listing tables with commas.

```
SELECT a.itemid, a.categoryid, MIN(b.price), MIN(b.stock), min(a.orderdate), count(*) as qty
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.categoryid = b.categoryid
GROUP BY a.itemid, a.categoryid
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to select COUNT(*)

Answer (score 0):

how about use following sql

```
select min(price), min(stock), min(orderDate), COUNT(categoryId) 
from A,B where A.categoryId = B.categoryId 
GROUP by A.categoryId
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create views for your subqueries and give them meaningful names e.g.  `CategoriesUsedInMultipleOrders`, `MostRecentOrderByCategory`. This would 'optimize' you query by abstracting away complexity and making it easier for the human reader to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Query with the appropriate join method [see Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb0OH.png):

```
SELECT B.price, B.stock, MIN( A.orderDate ) AS orderdate, COUNT( * ) AS qty
FROM TableA A, TableB B
WHERE A.categoryId = B.CategoryId
GROUP BY A.categoryId, B.price, B.stock
```